# Problem with package lineno

Tags: line-numbering

I'm using package `lineno` for proofreading of my documents.  So I usually have something like the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{ifthen}           % to use if then else
\newboolean{korrektur}        % for proofreading: true/false
 \setboolean{korrektur}{true} % choose one, comment the other
%\setboolean{korrektur}{false}

% What we need for proofreading
\ifthenelse{\boolean{korrektur}}% proofreading wanted?
{% YES:
  \usepackage{showframe}          % shows type area
  \usepackage{lineno}             % numbers lines
  \pagewiselinenumbers            % lines per page
}%
{% NO:
% error if lineno was used before:
  \typeout{***** Please delete .aux files if you get errors! *****}
% What to add here so that I get no errors?  %<=================
}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Run it two times. Everything should be well, blindtext is numbered.

Now please move the `%` sign from line 8 (false) to line 7 (true).

Because we had had the run before there is an `.aux`-file, including lines with the macro `\@LN`.

If you compile now you will get the following error message (and some more):

```
***** Please delete .aux files if you get errors! *****
(C:\Users\...\LaTeX\_TeX.SX\lineno\test-lineno.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \@LN
        {0}{0}
```

**Question**: 
Is it possible to add in line 20 (see `%<===========`) something to get rid of the error messages? Something that resets the meaning of macro `\@LN`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the error involving `\@LN` reports the macro to possibly take 2 arguments. This is confirmed from within [`lineno.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/lineno.sty):

```
\def\@LN#1#2{{\expandafter\@@LN
                 \csname LN@P#2C\@LN@column\expandafter\endcsname
                 \csname LN@PO#2\endcsname
                 {#1}{#2}}}
```

So, just add

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@LN}[2]{}
\makeatother
```

at the "base level" in your preamble (for example, just after `\documentclass{article}`). This will define `\@LN` (the missing macro) only if it is not already defined. Since the package defines `\@LN` via `\def`, it will be redefined if `lineno` is loaded.

If you which to provide this command within another command (like within the false clause of your conditional), then you need to place the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair *outside* the main conditional:

```
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{..}
  {% YES:
    %...
  }{% NO:
    %...
    \providecommand{\@LN}[2]{}%
  }
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to recompile from scratch (i.e., removing the `aux` file)?

My understanding is that the error is caused by the fact that the `lineno` package inserts the `\@LN` command in the `aux` file; as a consequence, the following steps

1. Compile the document with the package
2. Comment out the package
3. Compile again

will create an error, because the command `\@LN` is still in the `aux` file, but it is not defined.

Comment: My understanding is that OP wrote the original `***** Please delete .aux files if you get errors! *****`, so they're aware that removing the aux file is a solution.  But they're trying to find a more automated way to handle the issue.