# What is faster? To \RequirePackage{foo} or to check if the user has actually request it and \Require it if so?

Tags: best-practices, code

I'm asking this because the package [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) has a thing that leaves a lot of commands in the .aux file (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125777/problem-with-package-lineno))... and I'm not sure if I should `\newcommand` these to empty or if I should just load the package and forget about it.

I know the answer is very case dependent, as stated by David Carlisle:

> it depends. If the package is `tikz` then it loads 100 files and takes
>   half an hour doing stuff, if it is `indentfirst` then it doesn't.
>   Conversely loading `tikz` probably doesn't have an effect other than
>   taking time if no `tikz` commands are used, whereas loading `indentfirst`
>   in itself changes the document layout.

But I would like to know some other point of views, specially regarding best practices and if there is any approach that should be used for specific cases or with *delicate* packages.

Comment: `lineno` is not a spotless package. What are you after? (this is likely unrelated to the question, but it might be related to your problem, that's why I ask)

Comment: @tohecz it was similar to the question pointed out in the text.  I've decided to just load the package whether the line number option is set or not to avoid any problems, but I'm not sure if this should be done or if "asking" should be the way to go

Comment: Well, I more meant that you shouldn't rely on `lineno` package at all. There're other ways how to number lines, but this depends on the usage of this feature

Comment: The only time I notice a delay loading a package is when I don't have it installed yet.

Answer (score 5):

From my understanding of the `lineno` package, loading the package patches a number of low level things (e.g., `\vspace`, `\pagebreak`, `\nopagebreak`, and possible even `\\`) even if line numbering is never used. For this reason, it is probably best not to simply load the package and forget about it. I would also not `\newcommand` or `\def` your way around the crude in the `aux` file. When you remove the `lineno` package, I would simple delete the `aux` file.