# sharelatex undefined control sequence when compiling normal mode but not in draft

Tags: undefined

I get this error when I compile on sharelatex, but the strange thing is that it appears only when I'm compiling in normal mode and instead it works fluently when I'm compiling in draft mode (with sharelatex built in).

The error suggestions tells me the error is in chapter1.aux (that I don't have).

```
l.7 \@LN
        {0}{18}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any suggestions are appreciated since I can't understand how to fix it.

UPDATE: chapter1.tex is a file that I still have to complete and as of now is super simple:

```
\chapter{Introduction}  %Title of the First Chapter

\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{Chapter1/Figs/Raster/}{Chapter1/Figs/PDF/}{Chapter1/Figs/}}
\else
    \graphicspath{{Chapter1/Figs/Vector/}{Chapter1/Figs/}}
\fi

\todo[inline]{Write Introduction}

\section{Outline}
\todo[inline]{Write outline}
```

Comment: sharelatex isn't really involved, that just happens to be where you are running tex, but you have given no indication of your document how are we to help (short of searching the whole of ctan for a package that defines `\@LN` that you are presumably not loading. (most likely `lineno.sty` for line numbers

Comment: I'm using the "(CUED) LaTeX PhD Thesis Template", and pdflatex as compiler. I'm not an expert of latex but since I guess chapter1.aux is created from chapter1.tex, I updated the question to include chapter1.tex

Comment: In your preamble, add `\makeatletter \providecommand{\@LN}[2]{} \makeatother`.

Comment: Possibly related/cause: [Problem with package `lineno`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125779/5764)

Comment: @Werner ah well spotted, looks like a duplicate to me (+1 on your answer there:-)